# jquery css color change back and fortfh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change a color of a paragraph when a button is clicked. Click the button , p goes to green, click again, p goes to red.....
Why does my code not work?

```js
window.onload = function() {

  $('p').css('color', 'rgb(255,0,0)')

  $('#button').click(function() {
    color = $('p').css('color')
    if (color == 'rgb(255,0,0)') {
      $('p').css('color', 'green')

    } else {
      $('p').css('color', 'red')

    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Will try my jquery in this paragraph</p>
<button type="button" id="button">Click!</button>
```

Comment: `console.log(color)`

Comment: It works for me in Chrome if I add spaces after the commas: `color == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'`

Comment: You would be better off just toggling a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me in Chrome if I add spaces after the commas: `color == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'`

Since different browsers may return different strings for the color, the easiest thing to do in this case might be to save the string returned by `.css('color')` immediately after it's set, and then compare the `color` variable to that:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  $('p').css('color', 'rgb(255,0,0)');
  var match_red = $('p').css('color'); // save for matching

  $('#button').click(function() {
    color = $('p').css('color');
    if (color == match_red) {
      $('p').css('color', 'green');
    } else {
      $('p').css('color', 'red');
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Will try my jquery in this paragraph</p>
<button type="button" id="button">Click!</button>
```

That said, your code would be cleaner and easier to debug if you toggled CSS classes instead:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  $('#p').addClass('red'); // let's use a unique ID, too

  $('#button').click(function() {
      $('#p').toggleClass('red green');
  })
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="p">Will try my jquery in this paragraph</p>
<button type="button" id="button">Click!</button>
```

Comment: Yep, this is the way to do it. I would also touch on using the console log more often to output variable values for the sake of troubleshooting in instances such as these - in my testing, `console.log(color)` had output the value of `rgb(255, 0, 0)` making it clear at a glance that this would fail the conditional check against the value of `rgb(255,0,0)` with no spaces after commas.

Answer (score 2):

expanding on @ecasparello comment, you should be able to do:

```
window.onload = function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('p').toggleClass("green red");
  });
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="green">Will try my jquery in this paragraph</p>
<button type="button" id="button">Click!</button>
```

Comment: you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can toggle a class instead.

Advantages: you can toggle more properties than just the colour this way. I.e. font size, background color, borders, etc.

See demo below

```js
$(function() {
  $('p').addClass('red');

  $('#button').on('click', function() {
      $('p').toggleClass('blue red');
  });
});
```

```css
.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Will try my jquery in this paragraph</p>
<button type="button" id="button">Click!</button>
```

Comment: Clean and easy on the eyes.